# JavaScript output to a String

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to fetch javascript output to a string in java. I am working with `Selenium WebDriver` and I expect all child nodes to be listed for which I want to make use of javascript. I am making use of `JavascriptExecutor` functionality. I want something like this;

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)LaunchBrowserTest.driver;
List<String> s = (List<String>)(js.executeScript(" var text = 'aa'; "
            + "var list = document.getElementById('jstree'); "
            + "var anchorlist = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); "
            + "for( i = 0; i < anchorlist.length; i++ ) "
            + "{ "
            + "text = text + anchorlist[i].innerHTML; "
            + "};"
            + "console.log(text);"));
 System.out.println("String Array: " + s );
```

Is there any way I could expect the text outputted and captured into String 's' in java ?
After I get the list, I wanted them to be used in Selenium to click on the nodes as below

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText(s[i])); where i < s.length
```

The present output shows me `String Array: []`

Please suggest me changes/links to get the functionality working.

Answer:

```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)LaunchBrowserTest.driver;
    List<String> s = (List<String>)(js.executeScript(" var text = 'aa'; "
                + "var list = document.getElementById('jstree'); "
                + "var anchorlist = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); "
                + "for( i = 0; i < anchorlist.length; i++ ) "
                + "{ "
                + "text = text + anchorlist[i].innerHTML; "
                + "};"
                + "return text;"));
     System.out.println("String Array: " + s );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look through the documentation of Selenium JavascriptExecutor and look for the `executeScript()` method, you will see that your Javascript has to return something in 
order to catch it up in Java itself.

[Here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#method_detail) you can see what kind of data type you will get in Java if your JS script returns
anything.

I hope this helps you out, good luck.

Comment: I needed to add "return text;" to make it work in place of console.log(text). I was trying to write console output to some string. Thanks for pointing out. Made changes to my code above to point the correct statements to return.